# Assign name and value from dynamic table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

I have a table "Table01". Contents

[image]:

The above table is dynamic

Want code to read data from Table01 and assign value, example below:

```
Dim B_List_Only As String
Set B_List_Only = 10
```

not successful in any

Comment: The code is not reading anything, it is just (unsuccessfully) attempting to store a number in a string variable. The `Set` keyword is used for objects and has no place in these particular lines of code. Will there be more occurrences of `B_List_Only` or just one? What is the (tab) name of the worksheet? Is this code located in the same workbook as the table? Could you share more of your code and explain the bigger picture?

Comment: It seems you want to create variables where the name comes from the `"Name"` column of your table, and the value comes from `"Value"` column. To do that, you will need to write VBA code that modifies the VBA project itself. See the late Chip Pearson's article [Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx) for more information. Or you could create a dictionary, where the `key` is the `"Name"` and the `item` is the `"Value"`. Then refer to the variable with something like `myDict("B_List_Only")` which, in your case, would return `10`. Show your code for either  attempt.

Answer (score 1):

modify accrodingly

```
Sub AssignValueToTable()
    Dim iObj As ListObject
    Dim iSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As ListRow
    Dim nameValue

    Set iSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set iObj = iSheet.ListObjects("Table01")
    
    'loop each row in table
    For Each iRow In iObj.ListRows
        'assign value of column "Name" and row intersection
        nameValue = Intersect(iRow.Range, iObj.ListColumns("Name").Range).Value
        'check name value
        If nameValue = "B_List_Only" Then
        'assign value of column "Value" and row intersection
            Intersect(iRow.Range, iObj.ListColumns("Value").Range).Value = 10
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```